# SwiftUI EnvironmentObject ViewModel data not reflected in View

Tags: swift, swiftui

**ViewModel**
Api is called here and response is stored in watchLaterDataArr the variable

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pageCount = ""
    @Published var hasNoMoreRows = false
    @Published var watchLaterDataArr = [WatchLaterModelResponseData]()
        init(apiService: IStudioRepository) {
            self.apiService = apiService
        }
       func getWatchLaterListAPI() {
           apiService.getWatchLaterShoSeriesPage(page: self.pageCount)
               .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
               .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] (completion) in
                   switch completion {
                   case .finished:
                       break
                   case .failure(let error):
                   }
                   }, receiveValue: { response in
                       self.getStudioLatestReleasesSuccess(response)
               })
               .store(in: &self.cancellableBag)
       }
       func getStudioLatestReleasesSuccess(_ result: WatchLaterModel) {
           if(result.statusCode == 200) {
               for i in 0..<(result.response?.data.count)!{
                   if !self.hasNoMoreRows {
                  self.watchLaterDataArr.append((result.response?.data[i])!)
                   }
               }
               if result.response?.nextPage != nil && (result.response?.nextPage ?? "") != ""{
                   self.pageCount = result.response?.nextPage ?? ""
                   getWatchLaterListAPI()
               }
               else {
                   print(self.watchLaterDataArr.count)
                   self.hasNoMoreRows = true
               }
           }
       }  
}
```

**Views** In Views the data is not reflected the if condition is not satisfied or not called even when the view model is observableobject and publisher variable is used.

```
struct WatchLaterView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @EnvironmentObject var watchLaterViewModel:HomeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack{

                if (self.watchLaterViewModel.watchLaterDataArr.count > 0 && self.watchLaterViewModel.hasNoMoreRows) {
                    QGrid(self.watchLaterViewModel.watchLaterDataArr, columns: 3) {
                        StudioWatchLaterCellView(imageUrl: $0.thumbnailImage ?? "",videoItem: $0)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }.onAppear {
                self.watchLaterViewModel.getWatchLaterListAPI()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
    }
}
```

HomeView is called is tabBar like

```
HomeView().environmentObject(HomeViewModel(apiService: Constants.studioApiService))
                                .tabItem {
                                    Text("Home")
                                    self.isSelected == 0 ? Image("Home_selected") : Image("Home")
                            } .tag(0)
```

Help please the code is too big i can't shorten it anymore.

Comment: Did you try injecting `.environmentObject(...)` in SceneDelegate to your root view?

Comment: yeah i have tried it @pawello2222